# Sanding stained surface to tone down shade

Tags: sanding, stain

I am refurbishing an old door that had many coats of paint I removed. It has 7 panels, which I am staining, and the frame will be painted semi-gloss. After staining on one side of the door, I wasn't happy with the results because the surface, I speculate because of the previous coatings it had had, did not respond evenly to the stain and I decided to apply another coat to even it out. Even it out it did, however, now the stain is too dark and I would like it a little lighter, like it would have been after the first coat if it had been even. This is what it looks like after two coats:

[image]

Can I tone down the shade (thickness of stain) of this stain job by lightly sanding it, using maybe grit 120? I plan to put two coats of semi-gloss poly over the stain.

Comment: Simple sanding probably just dull it, instead of making it a lighter shade.  Poly might make it very slightly darker also.  It is easier to darken than to lighten stain/paint.

Comment: What if I applied some paint thinner with a small cloth?

Comment: Can try it in a corner, but think it will just smear or remove stain.  Would give it a day and see if you like dark colour more.